# Prevent place order using observer in magento 2

Tags: sales-order, magento-2.1.3, event-observer

Hi I'm trying to prevent placing order with the help of observer i have already trigger the event "**sales_order_place_before**" with this i got all the details of the order like products in cart ,shipping address etc.. so here i check some condition based on that i need to prevent the order from placing

can any one help me to do this

Comment: u got any solution?